# using the input from a user from the "prompt" window in my HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use the input of the user from the prompt window.

This is my JavaScript form:

```
var answer;

function load()
{
    answer=prompt("what is your name?", "Write your name here");    
    return answer;
}

function hideNsee() {   
  var HNS = document.getElementById("invite"); 
  if(HNS.style.display == "none") 
    HNS.style.display = "block"; 
  else HNS.style.display = "none"; 
}
```

and I want to use the input, in this case his or her name in my HTML invitation signature.

This is the invitation format, and the input will be in this case "shai".
[image: MY invitation]

for the second part, the user invites someone "Moshe Cohen" and this also is sent to the invitation.

How can I use the input and send it to the invitation?

When I try to save it to the "answer" VAR it does nothing.

I'm clearly missing something I need to do.

When I know how to take it from the prompt window I will cast this on the other inputs too, the invite, time, and place. 
I hope it will be the same method.

*this is the HTML part of my program, if its needed*

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css"/>
<script src="JavaScript.js">
</script>
</head>
<body onload= "load();">
         <span id="imvite">Invite:</span>
            <input
                  onmouseover="this.value=this.getAttribute('data-value');" 
                  data-value="Who is it?" 
                  onmouseout="this.value='';" 
        /> <br></br>


         <span id="time">Time:</span>
            <input
                 onmouseover="this.value=this.getAttribute('data-value');" 
                 data-value="At what time?" 
                 onmouseout="this.value='';" 
        /> <br></br>

         <span id="place">Place:</span>

        <input
              onmouseover="this.value='where is the event?';"
              onmouseout="this.value='';" 
        /> <br></br>

        <button onclick="hideNsee();">generate invite</button> 


        <div id="invite" style="display:none;"> 
            <div id="date">
             10/3/2015
             </div>
             <h1>Invitation<h1>





          </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what value does the answer var has when you input something in the prompt? "default data" ?

Comment: Can you add your script too .

Comment: Can you post hideNsee? Also Right now load() does not insert the answer anywhere so you do not need the return. When you generate just use `invitation += ' regards, '+answer;`

Comment: @mplungjan this is the hideNsee: function hideNsee() 
{ 
var HNS = document.getElementById("invite"); 
    if(HNS.style.display == "none")
 HNS.style.display = "block"; 
    else 
 HNS.style.display = "none"; 
}

Comment: @Vollmilchbb the answer var shold hold the user input.

Comment: Where is the invite code?

Comment: http://materializecss.com/modals.html

Comment: @mplungjan the invitation code is at the end, and its not much of a code, it should be like in the photo above. The text and 4 things I need to send to it. The name from the prompt, the name of the invited time and place. The question is how do I sent thos things to the invite. Like the bolded words in the photo.

Comment: I do not see any script adding the values to an invite

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking. How can I do that? I think that I need to treat all of them like string... What kind of script can I do to take this inputs and put them in the appropriate place in the invite like in the bolded text in the photo above?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean:

```
 function load() {
   answer=prompt("what is your name?", "Write your name here"); 
   var idInput = document.getElementById('nameId');
   idInput.value = answer;
 }
```

And in the HTML add the id to the element like so:

```
<input id="nameId"
              onmouseover="this.value=this.getAttribute('data-value');" 
              data-value="Who is it?" 
              onmouseout="this.value='';" 
    />
```

Comment: you are getting close to what im trying to do. but i dont need an input textbox inside my invitation. i only need the name that the user inserted at the propmpt box, this will be my signature, as you can see in the photo above. "shai". or did i got you wrong?

Comment: I have tried to. But it does not. I think that I have miss understood you. Can you show me  how did you ment that I will implement it in my code?